# OriginalSource of PreviewMouseUp event does not change on different sources of control

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a follow up of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385730). In the question the OP asked for a possibility, to only open a ComboBox, if the user clicks on the ToggleButton. If the user clicks somewhere else, nothing should happen.

My idea would have been to register to the `PreviewMouseUp` event, traverse up the visual tree of the original sender and set the `Handled` Property of the event arguments to `true` if a toggle button was found.

What I expect is that if I click somewhere on the toggle button a `ToggleButton` instance is found in the visual tree, if I click outside of it, a `ToggleButton` instance is not found.

What I see is, that a `ToggleButton` instance is found in both cases. In the WPF Visualizer I only find one `ToggleButton`. The `OriginalSource` property is always the `DockPanel` of the `ToggleButton`. Does someone have an explanation for that?

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox PreviewMouseUp="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var toggleButton = FindParent<ToggleButton>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
    e.Handled = toggleButton != null;
}

public T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    switch (parentObject)
    {
        //we've reached the end of the tree
        case null:
            return null;
        //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
        case T parent:
            return parent;
        //we move further to the root and keep looking
        default:
            return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you click "outside of the ToggleButton"?

Comment: And what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?